# Large Number of Node Modules after create-react-app eject

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, npm, create-react-app

I ran create-react-app eject because I wanted to use LESS on a project. I noticed after doing so the number of modules under node_modules in my project had significantly increased. I started another project with create-react-app, and after creating the app, I noticed there were a huge number of modules under node_modules. This was immediately after creating the app with no eject run. I have tried reinstalling create-react-app, node, and npm, and nothing will return the node_modules to the default configuration. I don't understand why ejecting one app would affect the configuration of all the future apps I create.

Comment: Have you recently updated your NPM version? Versions from 3 create a flat hierarchy in node_modules, instead of the nested structure on older versions.

Comment: I didn't update before running "eject" initially, but since I've reinstalled everything I guess I have the latest npm version now, so that would explain why even after a fresh install I don't get the nested hierarchy. However I'm still confused as to why running "eject" changed node_modules to a flat hierarchy. Unless running eject automatically updates npm? Thanks for the quick response!